# What is the hotkey for the spell next to the right click spell?

Tags: torchlight-2

How do I activate it?
Here's a picture of what I'm talking about.
http://i.snag.gy/ODKx1.jpg

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, if you want to know the hotkey for an action in a game, check the keybinding/control options page.

Comment: On a related note: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85456/how-do-you-use-function-keys-in-torchlight-2/85459#85459

Comment: @deutschZuid That was the first thing I did but I couldn't find anything relating.

Comment: @Rayz321 I think it's called action swapping or something along the line, not the most intuitive, but it's there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That spell overrides your current right-click spell by using <kbd>TAB</kbd> (default bindings).

You unfortunately will need to <kbd>TAB</kbd> between those two spells to use them.

If that proves too slow for you, you'll have to bind it to another key. Notice you already have it bound to <kbd>5</kbd>.

The answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85456/how-do-you-use-function-keys-in-torchlight-2/85459#85459) covers the keybinding issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also click to the spell menu (not the spell tree) and aim with your mouse to the spell that you want to key-assign, then press one of the function buttons (by those I mean any of them: <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>F5</kbd>, and so on...).

So when you want to use (e.g.) you assign a fireball spell, which was assigned to F1, you press that and there you have it.